# Copy File One folder to another folder in Google Drive using file name

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, copy

I have two folder in google drive account. "Folder 1" and "Folder 2".
inside "Folder 1" there is multiple file. lets say there is a file name `Test.txt` I want to copy the `Test.txt` file to "Folder 2" using Driveapp. I found code but it works only with "File Unique ID" is there anyway we can make it by file name only?

```
function copyfile() {

var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1pkwQ9te-EtpqC_NC3BoHzOTUoC7axZDcAfxrqMgslwg");

var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8_ub-Gf21e-fkxjSUwtczJGb3picl9LUVVPbnV6Vy1aRFRWc21IVjRkRjBPTV9xMWJLRFU")

var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8_ub-Gf21e-flJ4VmxvaWxmM2NpZHFyWWxRejE5Y09CRWdIZDhDQzBmU2JnZnhyMTU2ZHM")
// Make a backup copy.

var file2 = file.makeCopy('BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + file.getName());
dest_folder.addFile(file2);

source_folder.removeFile(file2);
  }
```

if i use file name instead of File Unqiue ID, i getting error:

> "TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object FileIterator. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to copy a file with the filename of `Test.txt` in the source folder to the destination folder by changing the filename.
- You want to copy the file using the filename.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the file using the filename, please use the method of `getFilesByName()`. In this case, "FileIterator" is returned, because the files of same filename can be existing at Google Drive.

  - When the filename is used for `getFileById(fileId)`, an error occurs.
  - Using this, in order to retrieve the file in the specific folder, please modify to `source_folder.getFilesByName(filename)`.
- When the file is copied, you can use the method of [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination). By this, the file can be directly copied to the destination folder.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the folder ID is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function copyfile() {
  var filename = "Test.txt";
  var sourceFolderId = "0B8_ub-Gf21e-fkxjSUwtczJGb3picl9LUVVPbnV6Vy1aRFRWc21IVjRkRjBPTV9xMWJLRFU";
  var destinationFolderId = "0B8_ub-Gf21e-flJ4VmxvaWxmM2NpZHFyWWxRejE5Y09CRWdIZDhDQzBmU2JnZnhyMTU2ZHM";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
  var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
    var srcFile = file.next();
    var newName = 'BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}
```

- When you run the script, if there is the file of the filename of `Test.txt` in the source folder, the file is copied to the destination folder.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the folder name is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function copyfile() {
  var filename = "Test.txt";
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
    var srcFile = file.next();
    var newName = 'BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}
```

- In this case, it supposes that the folders of `Folder 1` and `Folder 2` are existing in the Google Drive.

### References:

- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html)
- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)
- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName(String))
- [Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator.html)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to copy two files of "Test.txt" and "Test2.txt" in the folder `Folder 1`.

For this situation, how about the following script?

#### Sample script 1:

```
function copyfile() {
  var filenames = ["Test.txt", "Test2.txt"];
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    var filename = filenames[i];
    var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
      var srcFile = file.next();
      var newName = 'BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + srcFile.getName();
      srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
    }
  }
}
```

- If you want to add the filenames, please add them to the array of `filenames`.

#### Sample script 2:

If you want to copy all files in the folder of `Folder 1` to the folder of `Folder 2`, you can use the following script.

```
function copyfile() {
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  var files = source_folder.getFiles();
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var srcFile = files.next();
    var newName = 'BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks a lot. one more question. if i want to copy multiple file will it be possible? inside "Folder 1" there is two file "Test.txt" and "Test2.txt" want to copy to "Folder 1". thanks again

Comment: @firekid2018 Thank you for replying. For your additional request, I added two more sample scripts. Could you please confirm it? If those were not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you, code worked fine.i don't know if against rule. but now i need a lil bit more help. not sure if i need to create another topic for it. if it's against the rule let me know.after i saw your code i got an another idea to achieve my goal.  "var filenames = " can we read file name from a text file?lets say i upload a text file in my site "abc.com/filename.txt" inside the "filename.txt" i list the file name line by line (screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/tFEPZOX.jpg).
Test.txt
Test2.txt
and script  var filenames = value will read from the text file "abc.com/filename.txt". is it possible?