# Copy File One folder to another folder in Google Drive using file list from a text file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, copy

here is the original problem which answered by "Tanaike"
[Copy File One folder to another folder in Google Drive using file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332942/copy-file-one-folder-to-another-folder-in-google-drive-using-file-name)

can we get "var filenames = " value from a text file from gdrive

lets say i upload a text file in my gdrive folder name "abc" inside "abc" folder i have text file name "filename.txt" inside filename.txt i save some file name line by line. here is the screeshot of filename.txt 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB7Uk.jpg

filename.txt listed files are located inside "Folder 1". now i want script will retrieve the var filename value from "abc/filename.txt" and copy to "Folder 2"

```
function copyfile(e) {
  var filenames = DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\n").filter(String);
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    var filename = filenames[i];
    var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
      var srcFile = file.next();
      var newName = srcFile.getName();
      srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? I think that the values can be retrieved from the text file in Google Drive. But in your question, you want to upload the text file to your site. If my understanding is correct, I think that providing the specification for uploading the files to your site will help users think of the solution.

Comment: could you please guide how values can be retrieve from google drive text? i think this method will work for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to retrieve the filenames from the text file of `filename.txt`, you can use the script of `var filenames = DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\n").filter(String);`. But you want to upload the file to your site? I'm confused from your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: my english skill also bad. i tried `var filenames = DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\n").filter(String);` but it coping only the first line file name.

and can we set different path for the "filename.txt"

like in Mydrive=>"abc folder/filename.txt" script will retrive value from "abc folder/filename.txt". this soultion works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. `filenames` is an array. And in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your script for replicating your issue? Because I'm not sure about your current script. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. If you can do, please add it to your question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58334012/edit). By the way, you want to upload the file to your site? How about this?

Comment: first post edited, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the current script and the screenshot of [`filename.txt`](https://i.imgur.com/5JT348U.jpg), the files of `1.txt` and `2.txt` in `Folder 1` are copied to `Folder 2`. So unfortunately, the situation of `coping only the first line file name` cannot be replicated.

Comment: If there are several files with the filenames of `filename.txt`, this script might be useful. `var filenames = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("abc").next().getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\n").filter(String);`

Comment: yes i want to copy all the filename listed inside the `filename.txt` for me only `2.txt` coping. here the screenshot of `folder 2` https://i.imgur.com/5ErrZ9O.jpg

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Both files can be copied. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. So please confirm whether there are the files of `1.txt` and `2.txt` in `Folder 1` and also you have the permissions for copying both files and the values of `filenames` are an array including `1.txt` and `2.txt`.

Comment: oh got it. i needed to add `split("\r\n")`. works perfect. thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Comment: i have some limitation permission. when i trying to click accept i getting error `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

originally answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike

`var filenames = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("abc").next().getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\n").filter(String);`