# How can we run multiple function in single google drive app?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run two job in google drive app script in one single run, can we do that? sorry i am noob, i don't have much knowledge about php or scripting. here is sample code

```
function copyfile(e) {
  var filenames = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("abc").next().getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\r\n").filter(String);
  var sourceFolderName = "music";
  var destinationFolderId = "folder id 1";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    var filename = filenames[i];
    var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
      var srcFile = file.next();
      var newName = srcFile.getName();
      srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
    }
  }
   copyfile1(e); // Added
}

function copyfile1(e) {
  var filenames = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("abc").next().getFilesByName("filename.txt").next().getBlob().getDataAsString().split("\r\n").filter(String);
  var sourceFolderName = "music";
  var destinationFolderId = "folder id 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    var filename = filenames[i];
    var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
      var srcFile = file.next();
      var newName = srcFile.getName();
      srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer for Question 1:

When you want to run `myFunction2` after `myFunction1` was run, how about the following modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, by running `myFunction1`, `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` are run in order.

```
function myFunction1 () {
  code

  myFunction2(); // Added
}


function myFunction2 () {
  code
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, by running `main`, `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` are run in order.

```
function myFunction1 () {
  code
}


function myFunction2 () {
  code
}

// Added
function main() {
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
}
```

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

## Answer for Question 2:

- You want to run the function of `copyfile` by changing the variables of `filename`, `sourceFolderName` and `destinationFolderId`.

I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification? In this modification, the variables are put in an array which has the object as each element. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Sample script:

```
function copyfile(obj) {
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(obj.sourceFolderName).next();
  var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(obj.filename);
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.destinationFolderId);
    var srcFile = file.next();
    var newName = srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  // Please set this object.
  var object = [
    {filename: "filenames_value1", sourceFolderName: "sourceFolderName_value1", destinationFolderId: "destinationFolderId _value1"},
    {filename: "filenames_value2", sourceFolderName: "sourceFolderName_value2", destinationFolderId: "destinationFolderId _value2"}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    copyfile(object[i]);
  }
}
```

- Before you run the script, please set the variables of `filename`, `sourceFolderName` and `destinationFolderId` of the object of `object`.
- When you run the script, please run `main`.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply. i edited my first post. please tell me what i made wrong. kindly please tell me how can i use this method: 
 // Added
function main() {
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
}

this one looks easy to edit if i want to run 100 functions

Comment: @firekid2018 Thank you for replying. I'm surprised that your question was changed suddenly. If my answer didn't resolve your initial question, I have to apologize. At first, can I ask you whether your initial question was resolved? And I cannot understand about your replying. Can you explain about the relationship between your updated question and your replying? If you want to run the same function for several times, you can achieve it using the for loop. But I cannot understand about your current question. So I'm not sure whether this is what you want. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: i tried the Pattern 1 which you suggested. please check my first post code, kindly check if i made anything wrong. it only run the first function. sorry i don't have much knowledge about function.

Comment: if you see function copyfile(e) code. you will understand it's coping files one folder to another. i have multiple `var filenames` `var sourceFolderName` `var source_folder` what i want to do: in single script run check multiple `var filenames` `var sourceFolderName` `var source_folder` and move to according to `var source_folder`. so what i tried is to copy the first function and paste as second function only changed the variable. i am not sure if this work like this or not or i made some mistake. 

my english is not good either. let me know if you understand what i am asking.

Comment: @firekid2018 Thank you for replying. When I saw the script of your updated question, the difference between `copyfile` and `copyfile1` is only `destinationFolderId`. About `so what i tried is to copy the first function and paste as second function only changed the variable.`,  you want to run the function of `copyfile` by giving the several values of `destinationFolderId`. Is my understanding correct? If it's so, how about putting the values to an array and using it in `copyfile`? Please tell me whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: sorry my english and coding knowledge is poor. i have 
(`var filenames = "filenames_value1"` 
`var sourceFolderName = "sourceFolderName_value1"`
`var destinationFolderId = "destinationFolderId _value1"`)
and
(`var filenames = "filenames_value2"`
`var sourceFolderName = "sourceFolderName_value2`
`var destinationFolderId = "destinationFolderId _value2`)
i want to copy 'sourceFolderName_value1 to destinationFolderId _value1` and i also want to copy `filenames_value2 to destinationFolderId _value2` in one single script run.

Comment: @firekid2018 Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script for your new question. Could you please confirm it? In this modified script, you can add more variables to `object`. If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: script worked perfectly. and exactly like this script i was looking for. but here i can set only static file for copy. could you please guide me how  to "Copy File One folder to another folder in Google Drive using file list from a text file" yesterday you helped me to make that script. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334012/copy-file-one-folder-to-another-folder-in-google-drive-using-file-list-from-a-te i want to set var file a text file which will contain the filename which require to copy.